# Не выводится значение переменной

Tags: python

```
def eval():
    l = input('Enter L:')
    v = input('Enter V:')
    t = input('Enter t:')
    if l==None:
        v=int(v)
        t=int(t)
        res = v*t
        print(res)
    elif v==None:
        res = +l/+t
        print(res)
    elif t==None:
        res = +l/+v
        print(res)
```

Как вывести результат `res` ? `return` и `print` не возвращают значение в консоль.

---

Как можно вывести тот же результат `res` без использования консоли и `input`?
Если параметры `l`, `v`, `t` определены сразу в коде:

```
def eval(l,v,t):
```

Но как рассчитать l, v ,t не указывая значение (None) при вызове этой функции
`eval(4, ,7)` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если я правильно понял, то передается всегда только 2 аргумента. Во-первых, `input` всегда возвращает строку (если вы ничего не ввели, он возвратит пустую строку, а не `None`). Во-вторых, вы переводите строки в числах только в `if`, а в `elif` нет. В итоге функция должна выглядеть как-то так:

```
def eval():
    l = input('Enter L:')
    v = input('Enter V:')
    t = input('Enter t:')
    if l == '':
        print(int(v)*int(t))
    elif v == '':
        print(int(l)/int(t))
    elif t == '':
        print(int(l)/int(v))
```

Если хотите вызывать функцию из кода, можно объявить ее так

```
def eval(l = '', v = '', t = ''):
```

(если любой из аргументов не передан, он по умолчанию установится в `''`), но тогда при вызове надо будет указывать, какие именно аргументы вы передаете, например:

```
eval(l=9, t=3)
```

Хорошо бы добавить какой-нибудь вывод, если набор аргументов неправильный (добавить `else`, или выбрасывать исключение). И еще возможно стоит отказаться от использования названия `eval`, так как в питоне уже есть встроенная функция с таким названием.

Comment: Да, Вы верно поняли. Спасибо!